# Problem with 'for' loop in simple Gauss elimination code

Tags: c

I'm writing simple program for Gauss elimination. I feed my code with equation-matrix in external file with its order in first line - it reads correctly.
Then I'm dividing whole first row to end up with 1 in mD[0][0] - it also seem to work fine. Next, I'd like to get 0 in mDoc[1][0] in innermost 'for' (with k=0), then m[1][1]-(mDoc[1][0]/mDoc[0][0])*mDoc[0][1] for k=1 etc. And it works for mDoc[1][0] but then stops and nothing happens anymore like it does not iterate over >=1 k's.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    float m1[10][10], mDoc[10][10];
    int n, i, k, r;
    FILE *f;

    f=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
    if(f==NULL)
    {
    printf("No data\n");
    }

    fscanf(f," %d",&r);
    printf("%d\n",r);
    printf("M1:\n");
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        {
        for(k=0;k<=r;k++)
            {
            fscanf(f,"%f", &m1[i][k]);
            printf("%f ", m1[i][k]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    fclose(f);
    for (i=0;i<r;i++){
        for (k=0;k<=r;k++){
            mDoc[i][k]=m1[i][k];
        }
    }

for (n=0; n<=2; n++)
{
   for (k=n; k<=r; k++){
        mDoc[n][k]=m1[n][k]/m1[n][n];
   }

   for (i=n+1;i<=r;i++)
       for(k=0;k<=r;k++){
    mDoc[i][k]=mDoc[i][k]-(mDoc[i][n]/mDoc[n][n])*mDoc[n][k];
     printf("MD:\n");
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        {
        for(k=0;k<=r;k++)
            {
            printf("%f ", mDoc[i][k]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }    
}
}
```

For matrices:

```
m1 => mDoc= [2 4 6 2]
            [4 2 2 4]
            [6 4 2 6]
```

I'm getting

```
mDoc=[1 2 3 1] // first row as expected
     [0 2 2 4] // 0 also as I'd like it to be, but nothing more
     [6 4 2 6]
```

Can you see what's wrong with my thinking? Is it some typo or whole concept is flawed?

Matrix format:

```
r
x1 x2 x3 x4
x5 x6 x7 x8
x9 x10 x11 x12
```

Where r is the order of an equation and x[1-12] are the coefficients.

---

Sample input file:

```
3
2 4 6 2
4 2 2 4
6 4 2 6
```

Comment: `or (k=0;k<=r;k++){` <<-- are you sure?

Comment: Hmm, as I'd like to go with every element in each that row then I'd say that I'm sure. It doesn't work tho so maybe I shouldn't.

Comment: Maybe add some asserts, such as `assert (i < r);` [Or: post complete code, such that people can reproduce your problem]

Comment: I updated the code, it now produces problem that I wrote about. Obviously, it lacks backward substitution.

Comment: a.out: gauss2.c:54: main: Assertion `xxxx < nrow' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: It's hard for me to relate to it, I copied this exact code, compiled with gcc and it works without any warnings. It needs to be provided matrix in format that I provided in my first post, maybe that was the problem.

Comment: I copied your complete code, renamed the silly 1-letter variables, added a show_it() function, and a few asserts. One of the assert triggered, becaus your matrix is 3*4, and you address it as 4*4 somewhere.

Comment: What do you mean by 'silly variables'? How would you recommend to name them?

I changed every row-iterating 'for' boundries so that it never produces more than 2 and changed every comparison symbol to 'less than' but there's no difference in outcome.

Comment: I'm waiting for the question to reopen.... [ by silly, I mean that the i,j,k variables are hard to grep and to comprehend. Same for r  ] But the actual problem was the reuse of variables...

Comment: Posting sample file data would help.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I took the liberty to add it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, my rewrite:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define TEN 10

void show_it( double mx[][TEN], int nrow, int ncol);

void show_it( double mx[][TEN], int nrow, int ncol)
{
int irow, icol;

for(irow=0; irow < nrow; irow++) {
    for(icol=0; icol < ncol; icol++) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%lf ", mx[irow][icol]);
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    }
fprintf(stderr, "\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    double m1[TEN][TEN], mDoc[TEN][TEN];
    int xxxx, irow, icol, nrow, ncol;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", argv[1]);
    if(!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No data\n");
        exit(1);
    }

#if 1
        // Initialise with garbage to detect references to uninitialised entries
    memset(m1, 0x55, sizeof m1);
    memset(mDoc, 0x55, sizeof mDoc);
#endif

    fscanf(fp, " %d", &nrow);
    ncol = nrow+1;
    assert (ncol <= TEN);
    fprintf(stderr, "%d,%d\n", nrow, ncol);

    for(irow=0; irow < nrow; irow++) {
        for(icol=0; icol < ncol; icol++) {
            fscanf(fp, "%lf", &m1[irow][icol]);
            }
        }
    fclose(fp);

    fprintf(stderr, "M1:\n");
    show_it( m1, nrow, ncol);

        // Make a copy
    for (irow=0; irow < nrow; irow++){
        for (icol=0; icol < ncol; icol++){
            mDoc[irow][icol] = m1[irow][icol];
        }
    }

        // For row xxxx, set its diagonal element to 1.0; and scale the other columns accordingly
#if 0
    for (xxxx=0; xxxx < ncol; xxxx++) {
#else
    for (xxxx=0; xxxx < nrow; xxxx++) {
#endif
        for (icol=xxxx; icol < ncol; icol++){
                assert (xxxx < nrow);
                assert (xxxx < ncol);
                // You should check for divzero here...
            mDoc[xxxx][icol] /= m1[xxxx][xxxx];
            // mDoc[xxxx][icol] /= mDoc[xxxx][xxxx];
        }

                // Process the rows below xxxx
        for (irow=xxxx+1; irow < nrow; irow++) {
            for(icol=0; icol < ncol; icol++){
                assert (xxxx < nrow);
                assert (xxxx < ncol);
                // You could check for divzero here, but ...
                // The diagonal entries are already equal to 1.0 here; no need to divide by them
                // mDoc[irow][icol] -= (mDoc[irow][xxxx] / mDoc[xxxx][xxxx]) * mDoc[xxxx][icol];

                mDoc[irow][icol] -= (mDoc[irow][xxxx] ) * mDoc[xxxx][icol];
            }
        }
                //  Show intermediate result
        fprintf(stderr, "[Xxxx=%d] MD:\n", xxxx);
        show_it( mDoc, nrow, ncol);
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

---

- The actual problem appeared to be the instrumentation (it reused the i, j loop-variables): moving the print-intermediate-results to a function solved this.
- the original code actually was correct (except for the nrow/ncolumn thing, which would show up once the matrix would get larger)
- Gauss/Jordan without pivoting is a no-go area.
- you should not use float. always use double.
- one-letter identifiers might look cool, and maybe you are a mathematician, but they are not maintainable. Try to search(&replace) on `i`: good luck!
- the assert() statements are a good way to state and impose your pre-conditions. You might have been been wrong, after all.
- diagnostic output should go to stderr. It is much easier for (future) maintenance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help, that looks like a bit of work and time. I have to say I don't fully understand this code but maybe that's for the better. I'll have to think about it for a while.